# How a multidimensional array value assignation works in this case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, uppercase

Why this function does not return an string with the first letter of each word on upper case?

```
function titleCase(str) {
     str = str.split(' ');
     for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
         str[i][0] = str[i][0].toUpperCase(); 
         console.log(str);
     }
     return str;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please edit your answer to include what the output of your function is.

Comment: Simple way: `str.replace(/\b[a-z]/gi, (c) => c.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 5):

The reason Why this function does not return an string with the first letter of each word on upper case is because strings are **immutable**.

> *You cannot change a character within a string.*

Therefore this does not work in javascript:

```
str[i][0] = 'c';
```

This does not change the string `str[i]`.

However in order to achieve your goal you can *make a new string with first letter uppercase and assign it to the variable containing your string.*

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the whole array element with a new string. All you are doing is modifying a string but not what is in the array.

Then you need to join() the array again to get a string returned

```
function titleCase(str) {
     str = str.split(' ');
     for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
         str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].slice(1); 
       // ^^ reassign array element with new string ^^   
     }
     return str.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"capitalizeText" method used to covert first character of string to uppercase.

```
String.prototype.capitalizeText = String.prototype.capitalizeText || function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
 // return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

function titleCase(str) {
     str = str.split(' ');

     for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
         str[i] = str[i].capitalizeText(); 
         console.log(str[i]);
     }

     return str.join(" ");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#divResult b').text(titleCase("testing words"));
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w2ow768h/)

Comment: code only answer doesn't really answer the question without an explanation

Comment: @charlietfl : Done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Ty this:

```
function titleCase(str) {
     str = str.split(' ');
     for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
         str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].slice(1); 
         console.log(str[i], 'i');
     }
     return str;
}
```

to explain further:

Get the First letter and convert it to uppercase

```
str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()
```

This is the rest of the word without the first letter.

```
str[i].slice(1);
```

Comment: My bad, didn't saw other answers above before commenting this